# Error while configuring hibernate with a maven - restful webservices project in eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, rest, maven

I am new to maven and I have trouble setting up the required project environment. I created a maven project in eclipse and used jersey for restful web services. I am not sure how to add the hibernate dependency. I added the required hibernate jars as a user library, but when I run to run my application, I get this error

MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.pro.resource.ExitReasonsResource

Comment: Did you add the dependencies to pom.xml for hibernate? I am guessing its a web project, you are trying to deploy on which server?

Comment: No. i havent added anything in the pom.xml. I am new to this and not sure what to add. please help me with what has to be added in the pom.xml. I am using tomcat to deploy my project

Comment: well maven works in that way, all the jars that we used to add in the classpath, for each of the jar we have to specify the maven co-ordinates in the pom.xml inside the <dependencies> tag. Go to search.maven.org and search for hibernate-dependencies using their artifact id and add the dependencies in the pom.xml  http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/maven-hibernate-jpa/maven-and-hibernate-4-tutorial Here you will find example pom. I would also suggest to read about maven (at least beginner level reading).

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the project name and use the maven menu to "update project dependencies".  This might be a quick and easy fix.